# Setting constraints for dynamic views in iOS

Tags: swift, ios, user-interface

I have an app which uses Stack Views to update its UI depending on the number of pigs. For example below, 1 pig and 4 pigs.

[image]
[image]

I set up Stack Views in Storyboard and set isHidden to true based on how many pigs there are. I set up my custom view with my class below and set up x and y values of labels based on the current frame.

```
class PiggyBankView: UIView {

let titleLbl = UILabel()
let imageView = UIImageView()
let budgetLbl = CountingLabel()
let padding : CGFloat = 10.0
var parentFrame : CGRect?
var mainVC : MainVC?

init(parent : CGRect, frame : CGRect) {
    self.parentFrame = parent
    super.init(frame : frame)
    self.addCustomView()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addCustomView()
}


required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func addCustomView() {

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    //Set Padding For Image View
    let pad = padding * 2
    let innerSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width - pad, height: self.frame.size.height - pad)
    let innerFrame = CGRect(x: padding, y: padding, width: innerSize.width, height: innerSize.height)

    //Image View
    imageView.frame = innerFrame
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "pig-main")
    let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: imageView.frame.size.width / 2, y: imageView.frame.size.height / 2)

    // Title Label and Budget Label Based on its frame
    let size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width - pad, height: self.frame.size.height / 10)

    //Test
    self.setNeedsLayout()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    print("HEIGHT : \(self.frame.size.height), WIDTH : \(self.frame.size.width)")


    var parentHeight : CGFloat = 0.0
    var parentWidth : CGFloat = 0.0

    if let mainFrame = parentFrame {
        print(mainFrame.size.height)
        print(mainFrame.size.width)
        parentHeight = mainFrame.size.height
        parentWidth = mainFrame.size.width
    }

    let frameWidth = floor(self.frame.size.width)
    let frameHeight = floor(self.frame.size.height)
    var titleFrame : CGRect
    var labelFrame : CGRect
    var dragFromFrame : CGRect

    print("\(parentWidth / 2)")
    //TALL HEIGHT WIDE WIDTH
    if frameHeight == parentHeight && frameWidth == parentWidth {
        print("1 TALL HEIGHT / WIDE WIDTH ")
        titleFrame = CGRect(x: padding, y: (size.height * 2) - 20, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        labelFrame = CGRect(x: padding, y: (size.height * 7) + 25, width: size.width, height: size.height)



    // TALL HEIGHT SMALL WIDTH
    }else if frameHeight == parentHeight && frameWidth == floor(parentWidth / 2) {
        print("2 TALL HEIGHT / SMALL WIDTH")
        titleFrame = CGRect(x: padding, y: size.height * 3, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        labelFrame = CGRect(x: padding, y: size.height * 6 + 15, width: size.width, height: size.height)


    // SHORT HEIGHT - WIDE WIDTH
    }else if frameHeight == floor(parentHeight / 2) && frameWidth == parentWidth {
        print("3 SHORT HEIGHT / WIDE WIDTH Pig")
        titleFrame = CGRect(x: padding, y: -10, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        labelFrame = CGRect(x: padding, y: size.height * 9 + 10, width: size.width, height: size.height)


    // SHORT HEIGHT - SMALL WIDTH
    }else {
        print("4 SHORT HEIGHT / SHORT WIDTH Pig")
        titleFrame = CGRect(x: padding, y: (size.height * 2) - 10, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        labelFrame = CGRect(x: padding, y: (size.height * 7) + 15, width: size.width, height: size.height)

    }

    // Title label
    titleLbl.frame = titleFrame
    titleLbl.textAlignment = .center
    titleLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    titleLbl.font = UIFont(name: "CaviarDreams", size: 20.0)
    titleLbl.textColor = UIColor.black
    titleLbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    //Price Label
    let budgetFrame = CGRect(x: labelFrame.origin.x, y: labelFrame.origin.y, width: labelFrame.width * 0.8, height: labelFrame.height)
    budgetLbl.frame = budgetFrame
    budgetLbl.center = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: budgetFrame.origin.y)
    budgetLbl.textAlignment = .center
    budgetLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    budgetLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto", size: 16.0)
    budgetLbl.textColor = UIColor.black
    budgetLbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    self.addSubview(imageView)
    self.addSubview(titleLbl)
    self.addSubview(budgetLbl)
    self.addSubview(coinImageView)
    imageView.addSubview(dragFromView)
}
```

This gets the job done but I feel like my code is messy and unnecessary. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review, and yes! There is room for improvement here :)

First of all, I agree that this is worthy of subclassing UIView - there's enough here that I think makes sense to wrap these up into a custom component.

#### Property access level and names

When you're creating a custom view you want to keep all the subviews private. Otherwise some external view can grab a reference and do things like `myPiggy.titleLabel.removeFromSuperview()` instead, set these as `private` so they're only available from within the scope of your view.

I'd suggest not abbreviating the names. It's easier to read when it's a full word, and Xcode will autocomplete the properties so it's not like it's any faster to type by having shorter names.

```
class PiggyBankView: UIView {

    private let titleLabel = UILabel()
    private let imageView = UIImageView()
    private let budgetLabel = CountingLabel()

    //...
}
```

I'm assuming that somewhere in you're view controller you're setting the label text, and possibly pig color through these properties.

Instead, I'd pass this information in through the an initializer :

```
init(title: String, budget: String, pigImage: UIImage) {
        self.title = title
        // etc
}
```

#### Views should only be concerned about their subviews

You're keeping reference to the parent frame and the containing view controller:

```
//var parentFrame : CGRect?
//var mainVC : MainVC? // (I don't see this actually being used anywhere anyway)
```

And later in `addCustomView()` you're using the size of the parent frame to drive the layout logic.

```
if let mainFrame = parentFrame {
    parentHeight = mainFrame.size.height
    parentWidth = mainFrame.size.width
}
```

Views should never have to worry about that, and instead the containing view should have the responsibility for setting the size, position etc...

#### Make use of constraints and/or the view lifecycle

Without seeing how these views are using within the containing view controller I don't actually understand how these views are successfully resizing by toggling their `isHidden` property in a stack view (unless perhaps you're manually calling `addCustomView()` from the view controller but even then I'm not sure..)

Instead, I'd suggest either:

1. Defining constraints that allow the view to be adaptive (e.g. pin the pigImage to the left, right anchors of the view).
2. overriding `layoutSubviews()` to manually calculate and update the frames of your subviews as the frame of this view changes.

Personally I prefer constraints approach, but some find it off-putting because you can end up with a lot of verbose code.

I'm pretty sure that you will be able to set some relatively simple constraints that will greatly simplify your list of if/else statements that are checking for different combinations of wide/narrow/tall/short.

With the constraints set up, you'll also get the option of being able to set up a nice animation (if you want) of this view resizing in the stack view as different piggybank views are hidden/displayed.

If these `PiggyBankView`s are being managed by a `UIStackView` you'll also probably want to override `intrinsicContentSize`. I tend to end up using stack views with a `UIStackViewDistribution.fillProportionally` in which case the intrinsic content size is really used as a reference for the aspect ratio of the view, in your case the `PiggyBankView` is taller than wide because of the labels above and below the image so I'd return something like this:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 130)
}
```

which is a pointer for the stack view to set the height of the view to be 130% of the width that it's allocated.

#### Formatting

This may seem insignificant now, and you're mostly consistent, but in a few places you're adding a space before the colon that separates the property name and type:

```
// instead of this 
var titleFrame : CGRect

//do this
var titleFrame: CGRect
```

This is all pretty general feedback, but I hope it inspires you to go out and learn some more about views either for this or a future project!